# How to fix this problem with pip when i try to install packages? "TypeError: rmtree() got an unexpected keyword argument 'onexc' "

Tags: python, pip

When i try to install package using pip install:

```
pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\qq891\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\qq891\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\qq891\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\qq891\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\qq891\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2023.7.22)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 34, in global_tempdir_manager
    yield
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 571, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 144, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\build\build_tracker.py", line 44, in get_build_tracker
    with contextlib.ExitStack() as ctx:
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 586, in __exit__
    raise exc_details[1]
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 571, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 156, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 173, in cleanup
    rmtree(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 291, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 381, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 327, in iter
    raise retry_exc.reraise()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 160, in reraise
    raise self.last_attempt.result()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 384, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 128, in rmtree
    shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=ignore_errors, onexc=rmtree_errorhandler)
TypeError: rmtree() got an unexpected keyword argument 'onexc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 571, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 156, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 173, in cleanup
    rmtree(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 291, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 381, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 327, in iter
    raise retry_exc.reraise()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 160, in reraise
    raise self.last_attempt.result()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 384, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 128, in rmtree
    shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=ignore_errors, onexc=rmtree_errorhandler)
TypeError: rmtree() got an unexpected keyword argument 'onexc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 571, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 156, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 173, in cleanup
    rmtree(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 291, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 381, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 327, in iter
    raise retry_exc.reraise()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 160, in reraise
    raise self.last_attempt.result()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 384, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 128, in rmtree
    shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=ignore_errors, onexc=rmtree_errorhandler)
TypeError: rmtree() got an unexpected keyword argument 'onexc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 79, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 100, in main
    with self.main_context():
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 144, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\command_context.py", line 19, in main_context
    with self._main_context:
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 586, in __exit__
    raise exc_details[1]
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 571, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 155, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(value)
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 31, in global_tempdir_manager
    with ExitStack() as stack:
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 586, in __exit__
    raise exc_details[1]
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 571, in __exit__
    if cb(*exc_details):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 156, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 173, in cleanup
    rmtree(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 291, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 381, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 327, in iter
    raise retry_exc.reraise()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 160, in reraise
    raise self.last_attempt.result()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 384, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\qq891\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 128, in rmtree
    shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=ignore_errors, onexc=rmtree_errorhandler)
TypeError: rmtree() got an unexpected keyword argument 'onexc'
```

This error comes up with every package, not just with requests.

When I tried to update pip I got another error.

Comment: Before that I installed the miniconda package manager, but removed it shortly after that, maybe the problem appeared because of this, but I still don't know how to fix it

Comment: Can you check which version of pip (`pip -V`) and python (`python -V`) you are running?

Comment: You are using python 3.12 which is unreleased and still in beta

Comment: Try this command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` from Terminal Window. Please ensure `python` `path` is set in `Windows path` else Change Folder (`CD` or `ChDir`) to `python` installation folder before running the command from Terminal Windows or Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`)